# How to highlight or show new to the particular posts list

Tags: posts, css

I want to highlight or show the new tag to the particular posts. When the user selects that the post the should be highlighted or show the new tag in the post list, the post should show new tag in the posts list in Front-end.

How I can achieve this?

The New tag means the new image or new text to highlight the post in the post list to draw user attention.

[image]

This is my code added in `functions.php`:

```
function wpb_lastvisit_the_title ( $title, $id ) {
 
if ( is_singular() || get_post_type( $id ) == 'page' ) return $title;
 
// Check the post with the new tag 
$tag_ids = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID, array('fields' => 'ids'));

if ($tag_ids == 'new') 

$title .= '<span class="new-article">New</span>';
return $title;
}
 
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpb_lastvisit_the_title', 10, 2);
```

**CSS:**

```
.new-article { 
background: #feffdd;
padding: 3px;
border: 1px solid #eeefd2;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left:5px;
font-size: small;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does new tag mean? New taxonomy or what?  Can you correct your question? Add visual representation (Screenshots)?

Comment: @Unbywyd, New tag means the new image or new text to highlight the post in the post list to draw user attention.

Comment: @Unbywyd, As you have seen in the news website, they use the new image or text to highlight the post in the posts list to draw user attention.

Comment: I can help you, but I need more information, what is your template, and what type of post (page, post, custom type?)

Comment: @Unbywyd, I am using the default WordPress post template and default post lists.

Comment: please add a screenshot of your post lists

Comment: @Unbywyd, I have added the image and besides the title, I want to show the new image or new text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to display the latest posts you use default **Recent Posts** widget.

You can see it here: **Appearance -> Widgets**

This widget has no settings and is fine for getting started, you can install any plugin which will add a more sophisticated widget to your site, you just need to search for: **Recent Posts Widget**

**I found the following:**

- [Recent Posts Widget With Thumbnails](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails)
- [latest-posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-posts/)
- [smart-recent-posts-widget](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/smart-recent-posts-widget/)

And more...

Just go to plugins and add it to your site, then select it in widgets and customize accordingly

---

**Edit**

Change the **post title** relative to the **date** (if a month has not passed since the publication)

```
function wpb_lastvisit_the_title ( $title, $id ) {
    if ( is_singular() || get_post_type( $id ) != 'post' ) return $title;   

    $p = get_post( $id );
    $now = new DateTime();
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat(get_option( 'date_format' ), $p->post_date);
    if($date){
        $interval = $now->diff($date);

        $days = $interval->d;
        // If a month has not passed, show the label
        if($days <= 30) {
            $title .= ' <span class="new-article">New</span>';
        } 
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpb_lastvisit_the_title', 10, 2);
```

By tag:

```
function wpb_lastvisit_the_title ( $title, $id ) {
    if ( is_singular() || get_post_type( $id ) != 'post' ) return $title;

    $tag_ids = wp_get_post_tags($id, array('fields' => 'ids'));
    // tag with name - new
    $tagId = get_term_by('slug', 'new', 'post_tag') -> term_id;
  if(in_array($tagId, $tag_ids)) {
        $title .= ' <span class="new-article">New</span>';
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpb_lastvisit_the_title', 10, 2);
```

Comment: I know that, but I want that, if I want to highlight the post that is old 2 months and show new image to that post in the post list.

Comment: You cannot do this with a standard widget, or use a plugin which suits your requirements  as a last resort, create your own shortcode (programming knowledge required) with the output of post list as you like

Comment: In short, use a ready-made plugin or write your own, sorry, but there are no more answers to your very global question

Comment: Please check the image. Okay, But we can write the code for it. Like we can add the new in the tags and when the post has the new tag, we can add the new image before or after the title in the post list.

Comment: To do this, you need to write your own widget or shortcode, I already answered you, you cannot change the default widget

Comment: Please Check my question. I have added the code also.

Comment: Your example is working, what's the problem? Perhaps you want to use the difference in dates together to find out if a post is new?

Comment: ok, I see you also have errors in the code, I will correct

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is great.

Comment: I added both options for you, see answer

Comment: I added your code but it is showing new when I am opening the tag page. It is not showing new in the posts list that is displayed in the page.

Comment: Where is your posts widget located? On the homepage or on your own post page? My code is canceling showing on its own page (post page) and will only work on archive pages

Comment: Yes, It is showing in the archive page but I am showing the post list in my inner pages.

Comment: skip this check: is_singular():  if (get_post_type( $id ) != 'post' ) return $title; but this will lead to the fact that the pages of the post itself will also have a tag

Comment: Okay, But we have only  adding for the new tag.

Comment: // if ( is_singular() || get_post_type( $id ) != 'post' ) return $title; It is working now. It is showing new to the post list and only to the posts that have the new tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.